# How to download entire HTML of a webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url, download, firefox-addon

Is it possible to download the entire `HTML` of a webpage using `JavaScript` given the URL? What I want to do is to develop a Firefox add-on to download the content of all the links found in the source of current page of browser.

**update**: the URLs reside in the same domain

Comment: IS it similar to http://downthemall.net/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to do using jQuery ajax. Javascript in a Firefox extension is not subject to the cross-origin restriction. Here are some tips for using jQuery in a Firefox extension:

1. Add the jQuery library to your extension's chrome/content/ directory.
2. Load jQuery in the window load event callback rather than including it in your browser overlay XUL. Otherwise it can cause conflicts (e.g. clobbers a user's customized toolbar).

   ```
   (function(loader){ 
   loader.loadSubScript("chrome://ryebox/content/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"); })
   (Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader));
   ```
3. Use "jQuery" instead of "$". I experienced weird behavior when using $ instead of jQuery (a conflict of some kind I suppose)
4. Use jQuery(content.document) instead of jQuery(document) to access a page's DOM. In a Firefox extension "document" refers to the browser's XUL whereas "content.document" refers to the page's DOM.

I wrote a Firefox extension for getting bookmarks from my friend's bookmark site. It uses jQuery to fetch my bookmarks in a JSON response from his service, then creates a menu of those bookmarks so that I can easily access them. You can browse the source at https://github.com/erturne/ryebox

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript in general, the short answer is no, not unless all pages are within the same domain. JavaScript is limited by the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), so for security reasons, you cannot do cross-domain requests like that.

However, as pointed out by Max and erturne in the comments, when JavaScript is written as part of an extension/add-on to the browser, the regular rules about same origin policy and cross-domain requests does not seem to apply - at least not for Firefox and Chrome. Therefor, using JavaScript to download the pages should be possible using a XMLHttpRequest, or using some of the wrapper methods included in your favorite JS-library.

If you like me prefer jQuery, you can have a look at jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, that loads HTML from a given resource, and inject it into an element that you specify.

**Edit:**
Made some updates to my answer based on the comments about cross-domain requests made by add-ons.

Comment: Couldn't you use XMLHttpRequest to fetch those pages?

Comment: @Nobita Not as long as the resource resides on a different domain. XMLHttpRequest is restricted by the same origin policy. However, it can be used as long as the requests is posted within the same domain.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson There is 'firefox-addon' tag in this question, are you sure firefox addon can't request extra rights to load from different domain? Chrome addons have such capability.

Comment: @Max Interesting point, I expected the browser to run all JavaScript's under the same conditions, but I might be wrong there. Let's look in to it.

Comment: Yes I want to download the URLs within the same domain. Is it possible to make use of `JQuery` in a `Firefox add-on`?

Comment: @Meysam jQuery is just plain JavaScript, so I can't see why you shouldn't be able to use within your add-on.

Comment: JavaScript in a Firefox extension is not subject to the cross origin restriction.

Comment: @erturne Great to know. Do you have any good references to share?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I've never found a good comprehensive source for all the quirky stuff you'll run into when doing Firefox extension development. I've just learned it all by trial and error (e.g. a user called me to complain that my extension messed up their customized toolbar!). You can browse the source for one of my extensions at https://leapingmind.repositoryhosting.com/trac/leapingmind_ryebox/browser/firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can do XmlHttpRequests (XHR`s) if the combination scheme://domain:port is the same for the page hosting the JavaScript that should fetch the HTML.

Many JS-frameworks gives you easy XHR-support, Jquery, Dojo, etc. Example using DOJO:

```
function getText() {
  dojo.xhrGet({
    url: "test/someHtml.html",
        load: function(response, ioArgs){
      //The repsone is the HTML
      return response;
    },
    error: function(response, ioArgs){
      return response;
    },
    handleAs: "text"
  });
}
```

If you prefer writing your own XMLHttpRequest-handler, take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Answer (score -2):

if you only write a text web page downloader with your mind,and you only know `html` and `javascript`, you can write a downloader name "download.hta" with `html` and `javascript` to control `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` and `FSO`